# Formatting Date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just have an sql query that has a date in the format:

```
"2018-05-31"
```

Need to convert it to:

```
"May-18"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()),3) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR),2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function

`Select format(getdate(), 'MMM-yyyy')`

Answer (score 2):

SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMM yy')

Answer (score 1):

you can try below way

```
Declare @Date DateTime = '2018-05-31'
Select Format(@Date, N'MMM-yy')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/433d6/194

Answer (score 0):

`FORMAT` can be very slow. This looks a little less intuative, however, if you have a large dataset, will probably be much quicker:

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(11),GETDATE(),13),1,3,''),4,3,'-');
```

Answer (score 0):

This here could work:

```
 declare @date date  = '2018-05-31'



  select *, FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(1900, right(YearMonthKey,2), 1), 'MMMM', 'en-US') +'-'+ substring(YearMonthKey,3,2)  as MonthYearName from (
 select LEFT(CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @date, 112) AS INT),6) as YearMonthKey
)x
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `convert()` with style code `6` :

```
select replace(substring(convert(varchar(12), datecol, 6), 4, 6), ' ', '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way that a date or timestamp column is display at any time by altering your session to re-set nls_date_format. This will work in SQL*Plus or PL/SQL:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'MON-YY';
```